# "lateinit property <varName> has not been initialized" when using WebTestClient with SpringBootTest on Kotlin

Tags: spring, rest, testing, kotlin

I can not figure out how to get the `WebTestClient` initialized when using Kotlin and Spring Boot Tests.

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension::class, MockKExtension::class)
@AutoConfigureWebTestClient
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
class GraphQlClientIntegrationTest {
    private val testToken = "aUna%14OkmUZunb528342"

    @Autowired
    lateinit var client: WebTestClient

    @InjectMockKs
    lateinit var gateGraphQlClient: GateGraphQlClient

    @Test
    fun shouldAddAuthorization() {
        val ID = Id(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
        val returnResult = client.post()
                .uri("/graphql")
                .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, testToken)
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus().isOk
                .returnResult(ObjectNode::class.java)
    }
}
```

This is the error message

```
lateinit property client has not been initialized
kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property client has not been initialized
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try constructor injection. Because lateinit will initialize object lazily. So it will give `null` value when you call method so its throw `UninitializedPropertyAccessException`

```
class GraphQlClientIntegrationTest(val client: WebTestClient,
                                   val gateGraphQlClient: GateGraphQlClient) {
    private val testToken = "aUna%14OkmUZunb528342"
    // Your Code
}
```

Comment: Does this really work? I get: 'Test class should have exactly one public zero-argument constructor' (Using Kotlin 1.4.10)